# Custom blade directives not working - syntax error, unexpected ')'

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to create a blade directive that checks if the User is logged in AND has an activated account. In our database, we have a user_status column with 0: pending, 9 active.

// AppServiceProvider.php

```php
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('active', function () {
        $condition = false;

        // check if the user is authenticated
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // check if the user has a subscription
            if(auth()->user()->getStatus() == 9) {
                $condition = true;
            } else {
                $condition = false;
            }
        }

        return "<?php if ($condition) { ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('inactive', function () {
        return "<?php } else { ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('endactive', function () {
        return "<?php } ?>";
    });
}
```

// welcome.blade.php

```php
@active
    <p>User is active</p>
@inactive
    <p>User is inactive</p>
@endactive
```

I have included this getStatus() function on my User.php model.

```php
public function getStatus() {
    return $this->user_status;
}
```

I can also use the Trait MustActivateAccount, which includes this feature:

```php
/**
 * Determine if the user has activated account.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasActivatedAccount()
{
    return $this->user_status == 9;
}
```

This blade directive when added to the page says this error: 
**Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
syntax error, unexpected ')'**

Am I not escaping correctly in the AppServiceProvider.php file and if so where and how?

Comment: instead of this `auth()->user()->getStatus() == 9` use `Auth::user()->getStatus() == 9`

Comment: I don't think that error from blade directive, I've just tested your code and it's working fine. You need to check log to see more details.

Comment: @Josh did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the solution turned out to be the boolean `$condition` variable that had to be set as a string. `$condition = "true";` and not `$condition = true`.

This makes sense since the boolean would not `echo` out. Thus it would be `<?php if() { ?>` and not `<?php if(true) { ?>`.

See below (current version 6.18.41):

```
// check for Providers
Blade::directive('provider', function () {
   // check if the user has the correct type
   $condition = Auth::user()->type === "provider" ? "true" : "false"; // ... and not boolean
   return "<?php if (" . $condition . ") { ?>";
});
Blade::directive('endprovider', function () {
   return "<?php } ?>";
});
```

... and run: `php artisan view:clear`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your blade template

```
@if(Auth()->user()->user_status == 9)
    <p>User is active</p>
@else
    <p>User is inactive</p>
@endif
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The point was to use the directives.